# Where should I store M2Crypto files

Tags: python, python-3.x, m2crypto

I am using pyCharm. I ran the windowss installer of M2CryptoWin64 from:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/M2CryptoWin64
I first navigated to the location where I downloaded the M2CryptoWin64 (different location than the python file) and typed this command:

```
pip install --egg M2CryptoWin64
```

I successfully installed it. However, when I run my python scrypt, I get the following errors:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Users\xxx\PycharmProjects\TLSscanner\scanner_v1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import M2Crypto
  File "C:\Users\xxx\PycharmProjects\TLSscanner\M2Crypto\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    import __m2crypto
ImportError: No module named '__m2crypto'
```

Then, I moven the library folder and repeated the installation command line, which told me that the library already installed. I tried again, the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last M2Crypto version (0.28.1 in the time of editing this answer) works with python 3! https://mta.openssl.org/pipermail/openssl-users/2018-February/007463.html

Comment: Any chance that it has been finished now?

Comment: When that branch is finished, then it will be merged. Take [a look](https://gitlab.com/m2crypto/m2crypto/pipelines).

Comment: M2Crypto is now working both on py2k and py3k https://mta.openssl.org/pipermail/openssl-users/2018-February/007463.html

Comment: I have some errors in installing the M2Crypto package in Python3. Will you please help me out? https://stackoverflow.com/q/62412426/12116796